# Understanding nginx rate limiting

Tags: nginx, security, rate-limiting

I'm trying to configure rate limiting using nginx's `limit_req` feature to achieve a specific use case; I've been testing different options within my nginx configuration file, however, I can't seem to find the correct combination of options to achieve the following:

- Allow a burst of up to 400 requests in a minute (no delay)
- After the burst is used up, queue up to 100 requests
- process 6 request per second from the queue (delayed)
- if the queue size hits 100, return a HTTP 429 for new requests

I've tried several combinations of `burst`, `delay` and `nodelay` along with setting the request rate in `limit_req_zone` although I can't seem to achieve this, could you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Also related to this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/936670/nginx-rate-limiting-only-slowdown-if-ceiling-hit?rq=1

Comment: Have you tried burst=500 delay=400?

Comment: I have, but based on testing it appeared that no matter how many requests I sent i couldn't seem to 'fill' the queue to then generate the error, any ideas why this might be the case? (it effectively seems like the queue length is set infinitely high)